# Case insensitive query on JSON property in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb

We use MongoDb with MongoDb .Net Driver.

But in the Json documents, the property names can be pascalcase or camelcase.
How could use case insensitive query for property names?

```
 var filter = builder.Eq(propertyPath, value);
```

PropertyPath can be even 'User.Name' or 'user.name'.

Comment: A JSON document could have `user.name`, `User.Name`, `USER.NAME`, and any other case variation, all in the same document, if they have different values, which one should be matched?

Comment: Only one user.name exists (In any kind of upper/lower case) in our JSON.

Answer (score 0):

This is not directly supported. You can use $or to provide all possible values or canonicalize the field names when you are inserting the documents.